# IdentityServer 3 refresh tokens silently

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I'm using Identity Server 3 to authenticate / authorize a user in an MVC application.

The MVC application uses the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication method from IAppBuilder.

My MVC application has only one MVC controller which creates and Angular application.

Right now, when I make an ajax call and I get the response that the token has expired, I show a pop-up with a reload button that redirects that user to an action from HomeController which re authorizes the user through IS3 with a redirect.

My question - is there a way of doing this silently without having to use the pop-up and do the redirect?

Perhaps have an iFrame in the page that periodically makes requests to that action and saves the new tokens?

Or something similar ?

Is this doable in an Angular application which also uses a server side for authentication ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to renew the access token at the server side (Authorization code flow / Hybrid flow), you could make use of OIDC [refresh tokens](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokens).

I believe you are looking for client side libraries (SPA client - Implicit flow) to refresh the Access tokens. Yes. This is possible via iframe. Have a look at the [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki) JS library (look for signinSilent / automaticSilentRenew ) which renews Access tokens via iframe

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using refresh tokens on the server side. My question is if I can do still use refresh tokens but without having to redirect the client to identity server. Can I use the oidc-client library with Hybrid flows just for refreshing tokens in my case ?

Comment: @Mihai when you see a token expiry message / 401 response, intercept the request and make a request to backend MVC server for a new token. Since Angular app (SPA) is not a client to OP, you can't request refresh token from SPA. Is both your SPA and MVC  clients to OP ?

Comment: OP? I'm afraid I don't know what that is. My SPA is authorized through MVC. Should probably change that in the future and do the authorization through Javascript.